# How to make Mercurial subrepository to always point to a certain changeset or tag?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I am curious if this is possible with Mercurial. I'd like to have a subrepos in a project that are always fixed to the manually specified changeset, or better yet - tag.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to have a core system in the main repo and then all the modules and components in subrepos, but I don't want those subrepos to point to tip, only to the major releases of those components/modules(hence tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subrepositories work exactly like you want.

Mercurial never automatically update the subrepo to the tip. It always stays at the changeset you choose. From the [documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Synchronizing_in_subrepositories):

> Subrepos **don't automatically track the latest changeset of their
>   sources**. Instead, they are updated to the changeset that corresponds
>   with the changeset checked out in the top-level changeset. This is so
>   developers always get a consistent set of compatible code and
>   libraries when they update.

To achieve what you want, you can follow the following steps:

1. `echo subrepo = https://example.com/subrepo/repo/path > .hgsub`
2. `hg add .hgsub`
3. `hg clone https://example.com/subrepo/repo/path subrepo`
4. `hg -R subrepo update mytag`
5. `hg commit`

This will create a subrepo directory with the content of the specified repository which will stay on the `mytag` tag as long as you don't update **manually** to something else!

Everyone who clones your repository will have the subrepo on the same changeset as you (ie `mytag`).

FYI, the changeset to which a subrepo is updated is stored in the `.hgsubstate` file at the root of the main repository.